# Windows10でBash on Ubuntu on Windowsを使って公式 Swiftを動かす際の不具合

Tags: wsl

Windows10でBash on Ubuntu on Windowsを使って公式 Swiftを動かそうとし
ダウンロードして展開までできたのですがPATHを通すことができません。

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

を実行すると強制終了になってしまい

```
export PATH=/****/swift-4.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu16.10/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
```

を実行して

```
swift -version
```

を実行すると

```
swift: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

とメッセージがでてしまいます。

何が問題なのでしょうか。

Comment: `libtinfo.so.5` は端末(terminal)制御用の共有ライブラリで、おそらく libtinfo5 パッケージがインストールされていないのだと思われます。WSL(Ubuntu環境) で apt コマンドが利用できるのであれば、root 権限で `apt update; apt install libtinfo5` を実行すればインストールされるはずです。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。